# What event is raised when I return from launched by LaunchFileAsync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making some kind of file system browser for Windows Phone 8.1.
I can launch an app by calling Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() method, but how I can handle a moment, when launched application is closed and user returns back to my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register to handle the [Resuming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx) event. The event is raised whenever the user switches from an application back to yours.

```
partial class MainPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.Current.Resuming += new EventHandler<Object>(App_Resuming);
   }

   private void App_Resuming(Object sender, Object e)
   {
      //Refresh app/view/data
   }
}
```

The Resuming event is disabled during Debug. However, you can still debug the application behavior in response to this event by following [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for an answer, Red! Unfortunately, this event is not raised, at least in emulator.

Comment: This event is raised, for example, when I press on **Start** button and then hold **Back** button to switch back to my app. But when I'm just press **Back** from launched app, it doesn't raise

Comment: Taking my words back, it doesn't raise under debug.

Comment: @bonzaster I have edited the answer in response to handling App resuming during DEBUG.